# or rather what would be kind by me

Tags: meaning-in-context

> I have not said, exert yourself Harriet for my sake; think less, talk
> less of Mr. Elton for my sake; because for your own sake rather, I would wish it to be done, for the sake of what is more important than my comfort, a habit of self-command in you,a consideration of what is your duty, an attention to propriety, an endeavour to avoid the suspicions of others, to save your health and credit, and restore your tranquillity. These are the motives which I have been pressing on you. They are very important—and sorry I am that you cannot feel them sufficiently to act upon them. My being saved from pain is a very secondary consideration. I want you to save yourself from greater pain. Perhaps I may sometimes have felt that Harriet would not forget what was due—or **rather what would be kind by me**.”

Emma by Jane Austen chapter 13 volume 2

Context: Here Emma is trying to convince Harriet to forget about Elton and soon to be her wife, and move on from her attachment to him, which Emma herself had established, since she's the one that convinced Harriet that Elton loved her, when in fact he had been courting Emma.

What does the bold part mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emma is telling Harriet that she should forget about Mr Elton for her own (Harriet's) sake and not for Emma's. Then she adds as an afterthought that perhaps Harriet does owe her something - she starts to say 'what [is] due to me' and changes it to 'what would be kind by me' (we would say *to me* nowadays).